# Typescript not inferring dynamic key for object

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a simple redux action:

```js
export interface UpdateUserSettingsPayloadType {
  videoInput?: MediaDeviceInfo;
  audioInput?: MediaDeviceInfo;
  audioOutput?: MediaDeviceInfo;
}

export const updateUserSettings = (
  payload: UpdateUserSettingsPayloadType
): UserSettingsActionTypes => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS,
    payload,
  };
};
```

I am using an object to map the correct type from `MediaDeviceKind` to my state keys,

```js
// note `type` is type MediaDeviceKind = "audioinput" | "audiooutput" | "videoinput"

const typeMap = {
 audioinput: "audioInput",
 audiooutput: "audioOutput",
 videoinput: "videoInput",
};

dispatch(
  updateUserSettings({
    [`${typeMap[type]}`]: "a string", // <- incorrect
  })
);
```

It's only when I explicitly declare `audioInput` or `videoInput` as the key to the `updateUserSettings` param object that it displays an error.

```
dispatch(
  updateUserSettings({
    [`${typeMap[type]}`]: "I should error", // in
    audioInput: "i do error",
  })
);
```

### Update 1

I have realised that the key is being inferred as `[x: string]`:

[image]

When I actually need it to infer as `videoInput | audioInput | audioOutput`

This is what I except in terms of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, im not sure if I understand correctly? But you are trying to type verify the mediadevicekind, which doesnt happen now because it interprets the mapped values as string. Try to put "as const" behind your map and it will interpret them as the actual literals.

edit: Ok, so I think I understand what you want now:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GYm2mMwEDsH8ZD-VMMNTWUH2wjhuR1FAXn1HBPhwbCABZoGxEUCBNcthAARxQVwszBCRfxrOsCNQDESKFOo-nwE1-DAmAcFxXg-ypNDpEgpACkogR4PMItXBgAARLAjiwMJ5GZIDxVApirHlMwlRVNUNV6UBtSeTi9QNPibn6N4hhGMYAFUTAwOMEp9HAwywfBcUuOBdKkDUT083t+0SAB+fwbOLRznNcugUNWLomwq0Aqrsmr2RctB5Aa6k6E7crKtshynM6uqUOipoaBQZLUvSzLst2ajQAAChMGACroE9-EQJKUsGNLcAWnKdjyjbCowABKWwnxApocywSANR2Nbzq2q6jRm-asEOjKspOuAVsGAhLu0L65qO-6lqB1QTUuoA

However -> why dont you do it like this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEkCqkAmBDU1EGdoCcBlaUUASwDsBzbABTXABsB7NFWAXlgG9hZYBtANbRwsCrACy0FKTQARaADdSAY2gBpCigC6AfgBck6bIXK18cgDMmwAL4gVTctlCxMLw0lQYsuQsTIqWnpmVg5uXgEIGAk0SH5o6G1tQwByAAtoBmZUvgB6PNhsdKYAVwY2fDwmPDsHJxdYUu9MHHwiEgpqcIAKSBCWFE9kdFa-DsDqOkZBgEoOAD4IvkdnJgZoADpmSj6B1lm64GbR33aAruwe91BDoA

Comment: Hey Michiel, I have updated my question with screenshots to explain in more detail. Let me know if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: TS v4.1.2 infers key when using as const:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgWQIaJgXhgbwCgZ0BXAEwEsQKxESoAuGAIlMpAElb7mAaItlRD06jFoJAB5ET34wAbhTLJq3Mc0XLOavgQC+xCDFCQoBAiehwkyHDADkEmqPvnLscLdwIUGRAG0fZABdN3ArKGQrXEIYGECbPwSUYOCmZg4YCAALYQAbMhhkACdikGK+GH1zIA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgWQIaJgXhgbwCgZ0BXAEwEsQKxESoAuGAIlMpAElb7mAaItlRD06jFoJAB5ET34wAbhTLJq3Mc0XLOavgQC+xCDFCQoBAgHoLx8NDhJkOGAHIJNUc8MxUySugAiyIrAyADSNGQwVjCUEOgARgA2yEZQABaOyABOWSBZBCZ2CChOruRU7vSe0chgCcmpGTDZufkENFDZAGboITAcACopUAMO+ETE5dqiTIQw8-YoTNBZNADmcgvKwcgcZMtQq2BrE3r65oWwnXa4czAA2sVomI8OALpvTM4ZiYkg1dYIGlhIlIi08udzB1ur1HBwAKqIMjoTrwiDZADKyCgUHWEAACuh4H90JE7poVFxRAB+Jg+PyBHZcLogADcEwkVPotO8vgoASCFBCzLZHKm0igNLpfIFTLALPZZwKtlgJCRKOQaMx2NxxyMuAAFIgiST9v1EcjUeislicXjCcSQKSAJQ4AB843mhRAyQAdH81kaTU6yM7IWrLZrrbbdWsIAbrlBnUA

Comment: Hello Michiel, please see my link above showing where my issue is. Thanks for helping

Comment: @KarlTaylor - see revised answer